# Change an Outlook 2016 Contact Group photo using VBA

Tags: vba, microsoft-outlook

I am having trouble changing the photo in my address book for an Outlook 2016 **Contact Group**.

I cannot find the option to change the Contact Group photo within the application or within the Office 365 Outlook Web App. I have included screenshots below of what I am referring to.

I have some experience with VBA and thought that someone here might know of a way to modify this Using VBA in Outlook.

[image: Outlook 2016 Contact Group Screenshot]
[image: Outlook 365 Contact Group Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of May 12 2017, [Microsoft reports](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/edit-contact-group-photo/d8e9da5e-a47e-4e4c-ae31-a78417086cd5) the ability to do this does not exist.